# execute bash command works but not on crontab

Tags: bash, cron, amazon-lightsail

I am using aws lightsail product.

When i execute on bash the commend,

```
* * * * * docker exec -it my_container_name Rscript /home/path/to/file.R
```

I also checked cron log using

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

and it says it worked fine.
But the result is not given.

Comment: Try /path/to/docker instead of docker. Cron doesn't inherit your login environment.

Comment: Where do you expect a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why run **-it**  ?

Would it not be better to place the script in the container and run **-d** ?

Does the

Additional to that, your bash-env may be set up differently if you use cron rather than interactive login. PATHS , LC setting have caused me most issues.

Comment: Glad it helped... was it the env due to running as a cron job ?

Comment: I change *-it* to *-d*. then It worked only when the bash was running.

Answer (score 0):

Does your dockerimage file have an **ENTRYPOINT**

i.e.

```
copy run2.sh /usr/local/bin/run2.sh
run chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run2.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/run2.sh"]
```

Your run2.sh file should look something like this (so it can respond to Signals from the OS i.e. shutdown)

```
#!/bin/bash
#This is a run file - which should be used to add things you want your
#container to do when you start it up
#
#If you do not have this then ...
#  docker-compose up ---- simply exists as there is nothing for the container to do.

trap cleanup 1 2 3 6 9 15

cleanup()
{
  echo "Caught Signal ... cleaning up."
  service postgresql stop
  sleep 1s
  echo "Done  ... quitting."
  exit 1
}

service postgresql start
# wait forever
echo "Starting up"
while true
do
  tail -f /dev/null
done
```

Note: 
This removes the necessity to start services, plus you get to specify the shutdown steps required.

If you want you can have multiple rules, I was just lazy and lobbed them all together.

Hope this helps....